# an ANTLR Grammar for a statement or an exit statement

Tags: antlr, grammar, ebnf

I wrote down the following statement in an ANTLR grammar:

```
loopStatement
    : 'loop'  (statement|exit)* 'end' 'loop' ';'
    ;
```

If I understand correctly, `(statement|exit)*` means that I can have a `statement` or an `exit statement`. That is 
i.e `statement_1 exit_1`, or `statement_1`, or `statement_1 statement_2, exit_1`, right?
My parser works, besides when there's no the statement.
For example:

this works:

```
loop
x:=x+1;   <<< statement_1
exit when x=9; <<<<exit_1
end loop;
```

this works as well (no `exit`):

```
loop
x:=x+1;   <<< statement_1
          <<<<exit_1  (no exit)
end loop;
```

but this *DOES NOT* work (no `statement`):

```
loop
          <<< statement_1
exit when x=9; <<<<exit_1
end loop;
```

Is there anything wrong with my grammar?

Comment: You are talking about a grammar, not a regular expression

Comment: edit your title too; a lot of people know regex, but not EBNF. I added the EBNF tag for you

Comment: There is very likely a conflict with the rest of the grammar. It would be helpful if you added the rest of it, or at least the definitions of 'statement' and 'exit'.

Answer (score 3):

> *pantelis wrote:*
>
> If I understand correctly, `(statement|exit)*` means that I can have a `statement` or an `exit statement`.

To be precise, `(statement|exit)*` matches the empty string, or zero or more `statement` or `exit` statements (in no particular order!). So it'd match:

- statement statement statement ...
- exit exit exit ...
- exit exit statement statement exit ...
- ...

But, why not make your `exit` statement just a regular statement? I small demo:

```
loopStatement
  :  'loop'  statement* 'end' 'loop' ';'
  ;

statement
  :  'exit' 'when' expression ';' // exit statement
  |  ID ':=' expression ';'       // assignment
  ;

expression
  :  equalityExpression
  ;

equalityExpression
  :  addExpression ('=' addExpression)*
  ;

addExpression
  :  atom ('+' atom)*
  ;

atom
  :  ID
  |  Number
  |  '(' expression ')'
  ;

ID
  :  'a'..'z'+
  ;

Number
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;
```

which properly parses all your 3 examples:

---

### 1

```
loop
  x:=x+1;
  exit when x=9;
end loop;
```

[image]

---

### 2

```
loop
  x:=x+1;

end loop;
```

[image]

---

### 3

```
loop

  exit when x=9;
end loop;
```

[image]

---

### 4

Or nothing at all:

```
loop

end loop;
```

[image]